# Vampire--The Simian With a Canine Bite

Tags: internal-consistency, biology

In this more realistic scenario than typical fantasy, the vampire is just an ordinary human being with a certain genetic quirk that results in the following:

- A reversed circadian rhythm (active at night)
- A digestive system that accepts a more hypercarnivorous diet (in other words, meat and only meat)
- A stronger jaw with sharper teeth

Let's look up for the third point.  In regards to our jaw, the width is greater than its length.  For something similar, we need to look up brachycephalic breeds of dogs, narrowing the list to the Rottweiler, the breed reputed to have one of the strongest bites of any dog.

If we had a jaw more like a Rottweiler's, how strong will our bite force be?  How much will the muscles in the head area change to accommodate this sort of power?

Comment: Isn't thatba wolfman (or catman), not a vampire?

Comment: You should take a look at some of the simians with very powerful bites, chimps for example I seem to remember have impressive bite force although that's from memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you let the canines be thin and sharp and have the temporal muscle the sagittal crest like a gorilla 
[image: https://classconnection.s3.amazonaws.com/960/flashcards/855960/png/picture_51355197448990.png]

rather than

[image: http://familychiropracticstettler.ca/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/TMJ-muscles.jpg]

as humans have it. You would have a very effective hole punch. Even if you made the sagittal ridge more gracile and hidable then the Gorilla's.

Maybe this explains the vampiric fondness for hats and crazy hair.
[image: http://images2.fanpop.com/image/photos/10700000/Bram-Stoker-s-Dracula-bram-stokers-dracula-10765534-1024-576.jpg]
[image]

All this said the force of a human jaw is actually quite [strong and efficient](http://www.sciencealert.com/human-bite-stronger-than-apes) .  Sharp pointy teeth would probably suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably have a very powerful, thick neck, and very well developed jaw muscles.

However, Vampires are well known for seeking the blood of their victims, not their meat - that's more of a Werewolf thing.

For a creature to feed on people's blood it wouldn't need to have an insanely powerful bite. It would, however, benefit from being able to paralyze, charm, or otherwise subdue it's victims.

Comment: Blood is poor in nutrients.  Might work for someone with a two-inch wingspan, but for a six-foot primate, blood alone just won't cut it.